# Disable past days in Litepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using Litepicker: https://litepicker.com/
How can I disable the past days in the calendar? For example if today is 7th, I need to disable clicking and the color has to be grey of the past days (6th, 5th,...).

Answer (score 0):

Litepicker docs:

> Disable days for select. Can contains array with range:
> Eg: [ [‘2019-01-01’, ‘2019-01-10’], ‘2019-01-31’ ].Can contains Date Object or Unix Timestamp (with milliseconds) or String (must be equal to option lockDaysFormat).
> Default: "YYYY-MM-DD" Date format for option lockDays.

Use moment.js to get today's date, subtract a day, then use an artitrary date set way in the past. You could use your 'setMin' date if using one, otherwise this also still works.

For example...

```
let format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'; //<-- Change this to the date format your using for your project, otherwise this doesn't matter keep it the same.
let today = moment(); //Gets today's date in a moment object
today.subtract(1,'days').format(format); //Subtract a day, then format to whatever your 'lockDaysFormat' string is.
const disallowedDates = [['2001-01-01', today]]//Make a 2D array with those those variables.

//Put in your litepicker settings..
new Litepicker({
  element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
  singleMode: false,
  lockDaysFormat:format, //<-- Format used above with moment
  lockDays:disallowedDates, //<-- Disable dates
})
```